# Trouble accessing remote JSON in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json, jsonp

So, I have been working on this exercise and I'm down to one final problem.

The JSON is on a different server.  If I use a plain old `$http.get` then it doesn't allow the cross-server request. When I switch and use `$http.jsonp` I get to the file but it claims an unexpected ":" right away. I've validated their JSON so I'm not sure what's going on.

This is the current implementation of the call:

```
app.factory('users', ['$http', function($http) { 
return {
    callExternalJson: function() {
        return $http.jsonp('http://applicant.pointsource.us/api/testUser/577ebf34f62a2d8f3c05d9c0?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').then( function(response) {
            return response;
        });
    }
}
}]);
```

How do I get that remote JSON file?

Something to note: that remote JSON changes every time you hit it.

I also tried a different way of using jsonp that I've used in the past to access other RESTful APIs and got the same result of it choking on their first colon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't your code, but instead the server.

Try replacing the URL with this Test URL that supports JSONP.  http://ip.jsontest.com/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK

Comment: Ok,.that's a little reassuring, but now how do I access that remote JSON?

Comment: Without access to the server, this becomes a more difficult problem.  As far as I know, you would need to create a middle tier.  For instance, set up a simple server (node.js would work well).  You would then call your custom server URI in the $http code, and the server would then fetch this data from the pointsource.us server.

Comment: Sheesh! That's a pain for a simple coding exercise!

Comment: What is this exercise for?  Are there any instructions or constraints that may shed some light on what is expected?

Comment: It's a code test for a job interview. They have the json at the link above and you need to retrieve it and display it in a certain fashion. Something tells me I ain't getting this one! LOL!

Comment: It is possible the error is on their end.  If you inspect the Web traffic, it is clear that they do not accept any traffic outside http://localhost:8080.  One way around it is if you host your answer on a local server with port 8080 :P

Comment: When I host the identical file locally and use a plain old http.get, the whole thing works fine. I just can't access the JSON on their server. I may have to admit defeat on this one.